# Distribution of key by server

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, key-generation, key-exchange

I have read that in asymmetric cryptography, a system admin can generate key pairs on the server. After that, the users will be given the generated key pairs and this is an efficient way of doing this kind of thing.

I have two questions:

1. How can the admin. distribute the key pairs? If say, via email, isn't it time-consuming?
2. I thought private key should be private...but the admin. actually knows it as well?

Comment: Are you also familiar with the idea of "PKI". This answers much of your question.

Comment: I thought PKI is having a CA that verifies your public key and deal with those admin. thing e.g. revoke a cert etc.? How does it help?

Comment: Maybe I need to ask a more basic question. Why do you think the server admin generates keys and sends BOTH to a user?

Comment: um...I guess he can just send the private key. An users can find other public keys in the server.

Comment: Why does the user need the private key?

Comment: So they can use it to, say, sign a message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21451/discussion-between-xcoder-and-schroeder).